# Responsive Datagrid vertically when maximize the window

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I'm trying to set the height of the rows in the datagrid dynamically , I mean the height of the datagrid should be based on the data binding ( from the database ) , I don't have a problem with columns , they are responsive when I maximize the window the columns increase and take the available space.
The problem now is with rows so what I need exactly is when I maximize the Window , the datagrid should take the available space vertically ( increase the font size of the headers and the data shown in the datagrid).

Is there any possibility to make the rows of the datagrid responsive ?

Xaml Code:

```
<DockPanel Grid.Row="2" Width="auto" MinWidth="800" Height="auto" >
   <ScrollViewer ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
      <DataGrid  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="20" Height="auto" Width="auto" GridLinesVisibility="All"  ItemsSource="{Binding GridModel}" x:Name="UserGrid" MinWidth="1200"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" FlowDirection="RightToLeft" 
                 AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserAddRows="false" MinHeight="800"  
                 Grid.RowSpan="2" RenderTransformOrigin="0.497,0.551" MouseDoubleClick="UserGrid_MouseDoubleClick" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">

         <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
               <Setter Property="Height" Value="Auto"/>
            </Style>
         </DataGrid.RowStyle>
         <DataGrid.Resources>

            <Style  x:Key="DisableSelection" TargetType="DataGridCell">
               <!--  <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/> -->
               <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
               <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
               <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Style>
         </DataGrid.Resources>
         <DataGrid.Columns>

            <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="choose" x:Name="choose" Binding="{Binding isChecked}" >

               <DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>

                  <Style  TargetType="DataGridCell"  BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
                     <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                           <Setter Property="IsEditing" Value="True"/>
                        </Trigger>
                     </Style.Triggers>
                     <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Checked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                     <EventSetter Event="CheckBox.Unchecked" Handler="OnChecked"/>
                     <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />

                  </Style>

               </DataGridCheckBoxColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>

            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource DisableSelection}" Header="IDw" x:Name="workIdcl" Binding="{Binding wId}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource DisableSelection}" Header="subName" x:Name="subscriberNamecl" Binding="{Binding subName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*" CellStyle="{StaticResource DisableSelection}" Header="UserName" x:Name="patientNamecl"   Binding="{Binding UserName}" IsReadOnly="True" />

         </DataGrid.Columns>

      </DataGrid>
   </ScrollViewer>

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: You could scale the entire datagrid or a parent container by putting it inside a viewbox.

Comment: And what about the DockPanel?

Comment: Can you give me some code in my case how can I use the ViewBox ? what are the properties that should I use in the ViewBox?

Comment: You need to have a fixed size for it's child so whatever you put the <ViewBox> opening and </ViewBox> closing tags around, set that element's size. Your dockpanel seems pointless. And why do you have a scrollviewer around the datagrid which has a scrollviewer itself? Both seem pointless.

Comment: I have fixed this, and I have remove the other scrollviewer , so for now I have only a scrollViewer inside the datagrid . I have tested the ViewBox but I didn't get what I need , it scale the content but I have lost the data inside the datagrid when I have used the ViewBox

Comment: That's probably the stackpanel interfering. Plan B then.  You could try a Rendertransform on the datagrid with a 
 scaletransform. Try hard coding the values initially to check it'll work with scalex and scaley to say 2. If that's ok then you can calculate the scaling you want using whatever your logic is.

Comment: A `DatatGridView` and a `DataGrid` are two (2) different things. Calling a WPF `DataGrid` a  winforms `DataGridView` is incorrect and confusing.

Comment: @JohnG I have corrected it and I have updated my question , thanks for the remark

Comment: If rendertransform doesn't suit, you could set fontsize via a style. Bind the value. Experiment with resizing your window to see what height suits whst size.  12 up to n, 13 up to n *1.25 abd so on.  Set the bound value depending on which range the height falls in when the window is resized.